# How to implicitly update nodes in Android firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Structure of my database]

In my app, users can create a post, and update their profile picture, but when they do, their profile picture of their created posts does not change. I thought I solved it with the following code, but it was not.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

In BD I have the following structure as seen in the image, and in each post id the data of the user id are saved, what I want to do is that regardless of the post id in all children where the userId node is the same  To the current user the userPhoto node is updated, I thought that with the image code it would be enough but what it does is create a new child node of Posts but it is not what I am looking for how could I solve what they think.

```
final DatabaseReference sd = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");
Query query = sd.orderByChild("userPhoto").equalTo(currentUsers.getPhotoUrl().toString());
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        HashMap<String, Object> maps = new HashMap<>();
        maps.put("userPhoto", ""+mUri);
        sd.updateChildren(maps);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the `userPhoto` under the id, then you can do the following:

```
final DatabaseReference sd = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

Query query = sd.orderByChild("userPhoto").equalTo(currentUsers.getPhotoUrl().toString());
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
        String key = ds.getKey();
        HashMap<String, Object> maps = new HashMap<>();
        maps.put("userPhoto", ""+mUri);
        sd.child(key).updateChildren(maps);
      }
   }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Since you are doing a query, then all you need to do is iterate and then you will retrieve the correct random id, and then use it in the path `child(key)`

Comment: you're a genius, it was just what i was looking for. Thank you very much for your help, greetings from Mexico